# First principle of thermodynamics with kinetic and potential energies

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, work, potential-energy

Edit: Sometimes the first principle is stated as $Q+W=\Delta U\;+\Delta K\;+\Delta P$ (1). I assumed that the expression comes from the more elementary principle $Q+W_{total}=\Delta U$. On the one hand, if the work of the conservative forces is computed, the expression will take the form $Q+W_{nc}=\Delta U\;+\Delta P$, where the subscript *nc*  indicates it is the work produced by the non-conservative forces. On the other hand, if the total work is computed, using the work-energy theorem, it follows that $Q=\Delta U\;+\Delta K$. Then, how can there be simultaneously a work term and kinetic and potential energy terms in (1)?

I did the work-energy result hoping to get some insight on the question. The total work is given by  $$W=\int\limits_{C}\textbf{F}\cdot\textbf{dl}$$
Using the following parametrisation $$\textbf{r}=(x(t),y(z),z(t))$$ Whose derivative is the velocity vector $$\textbf{r'}=\textbf{v}=(v_{x}(t),v_{y}(t),v_{z}(t))$$ Then the work becomes $$W=\int\limits_{a}^b\textbf{F}\cdot \textbf{v}\mathrm{d}t$$ Applying Newton's Law (from an inertial reference system) $$W=m\int\limits_{a}^b\textbf{v'}\cdot \textbf{v}\mathrm{d}t$$ $$W=m\left(\int\limits_{a}^bv_{x}v'_{x}\mathrm{d}t\;+\;\int\limits_{a}^bv_{y}v'_{y}\mathrm{d}t\;+\;\int\limits_{a}^bv_{z}v'_{z}\mathrm{d}t\right)$$ Using the change of variable theorem (alpha is just a dummy variable) $$W=m\left(\int\limits_{v_{x}(a)}^{v_{x}(b)}\alpha\mathrm{d}\alpha\;+\;\int\limits_{v_{y}(a)}^{v_{y}(b)}\alpha\mathrm{d}\alpha\;+\;\int\limits_{v_{z}(a)}^{v_{z}(b)}\alpha\mathrm{d}\alpha\right)$$ Defining $p_{1}:=p(a)$ and $p_{2}:=p(b)$ where p is any property and $K(t):=\frac{m}{2}\left(v_{x}(t)^2+v_{y}(t)^2+v_{z}(t)^2\right)$, the work produced by conservative and non-conservative forces is given by: $$W=K_{2}-K_{1}$$

Comment: Your question seems to be about mechanics, not thermodynamics. You are writing an energy balance for a system that has neither potential nor internal energy. $W=K_2-K_1$ certainly applies to a point particle moving on a straight line under the action of a force. What you are asking is unclear.

Comment: You're correct that the net work done on an object (by all forces, conservative & non-conservative) is equal to the change in the kinetic energy of the object.  I'm not clear what statement you're arguing against in your first sentence;  can you [edit] your question to elaborate on that?

Comment: I don't understand when you say "On the other hand, if the total work is computed, using the work-energy theorem, it follows that $Q=\Delta U\;+\Delta K$". Unclear under what conditions you get the last equation.

Answer (score 0):

Work in thermodynamics is done under *quasistatic* conditions, which is to say, the applied force does not produce acceleration because it is balanced precisely by an opposing force due to the pressure of the system. The situation is illustrated below:

[image]

As a result of the force balance the velocity of the piston is $v\to 0$.